# Is a sqlite3 online backup valid in a running transaction without the journal file

Tags: c++, sqlite, transactions, database-backups

I used the backup API of sqlite3 to create online backups of my sqlite3 databases as described in [Example 2](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html). Sqlite3 saves additionally to the database a journal file in case of a transaction to make the rollback possible. It seams as if this leads to problems if a backup is written, while a transaction is running.

So if a backup is created while a transaction is running, is the resulting backup still valid without a journal file? I already did some research, but could not find any information of what has to be done to ensure valid backups of an database. Has the journal file to be copied or does the backup API takes care of everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A backup uses the normal transacation mechanism to access the database, so it is not possible for the backup to be in an inconsistent state.
(When in journal rollback mode, the backup transaction would be blocked while somebody else is writing; when in WAL mode, the backup has the state before the write transaction began.)